# Disable warnings in llvm-gcc

Tags: makefile, suppress-warnings, llvm-gcc, klee

I'm trying to build an open source project with `llvm-gcc 4.2` with `-emit-llvm` flag.
However I get many errors due to warning flags.

Example of these errors:

```
cc1: error: unrecognized command line option "-Warray-bounds"
cc1: error: unrecognized command line option "-Wjump-misses-init"
cc1: error: unrecognized command line option "-Wvla"
cc1: error: unrecognized command line option "-Wignored-qualifiers"
cc1: error: unrecognized command line option "-Wlogical-op"
cc1: error: unrecognized command line option "-fexcess-precision=fast"
```

In `clang` I would use `-Wno-error` to ignore them, but that doesn't seem to work with `llvm-gcc`.
Manually removing the flags does not seem reasonable considering that there are 144 `Makefiles`.

How would I approach this problem?

Comment: You mean you would suppress CLI syntax errors with -Wno-error? I doubt that.

Comment: At least clang didn't bother me with it.

Comment: I'm afraid you're just using command line options not recognized by the tool you are using. That has nothing to do with compilation errors or warnings.

Comment: So my only option would be to manually removing those options?

Comment: Basically yes, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was trying hard to search for recent information on `llvm-gcc` and failed. I concluded that it's a dead project that was part of former LLVM releases but is no longer actively developed. Therefore it doesn't support the same set of warnings as current GCC versions and you cannot expect it to work with the same command line.

The errors you're getting tell you which CLI options are not supported and you have no choice than to remove them or stop using llvm-gcc and switch to something more modern. According to the LLVM website, the project you're looking for is called *dragonegg*.

http://dragonegg.llvm.org/

Comment: Thanks. I can't use a newer tool mainly because KLEE only support the usage of LLVM 2.9 which is used by llvm-gcc 4.2

Comment: No problem. It's good to include those details in the question. Klee is one interesting piece of information, another would be why you prefer llvm-gcc over clang.